# How to count all the files from directory and subdirectories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I am trying to find the length of all the files. When I print the `f`, it give me all the filenames from the directory and the subdiretories also but when I print the `length` it gave me this result.

```
4
7
7
3
```

I printed the `length` outside the loop also but it didn't count the files in sudirectories.

**Code**

```
import os
path = '/home/runner/TestP1'

for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(path):
  for f in f_names:
    length = len(f)
    print(length)
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the sum of the length of all file names, or how many files and folders are in your directory and subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `for f in f_names:` you're iterating through the list of file names in the current `root` directory, so `len(f)` returns the length of each file name as a string, which is not what you want.

You can instead use the `sum` function with a generator expression that outputs the lengths of the lists of file names yielded by `os.walk`:

```
sum(len(filenames) for _, _, filenames in os.walk(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable outside the `for`-Loops so it is available for all consequent loops to append your filename lengths to:

```
import os
path = '/home/runner/TestP1'

lenghs = []
for root,d_names,f_names in os.walk(path):
  for f in f_names:
    lenghs.append(len(f))

print(lengths)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def fileCount:
        count = 0
        for filename in os.listdir(folder):
            path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                count += 1
            elif os.path.isfolder(path):
                count += fileCount(path)
        return count
```